# Node JS | Grabbing last 7 days of data from the database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to get last 7 days of data from my database. I have a table called `date` and I know that I could easily use `date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY` but that won't work for me because I have `date` values like that: `Jan 22 2017 16: +0`, `Jan 22 2017 15: +0`, `Jan 22 2017 14: +0`, `Jan 22 2017 13: +0`, `Jan 22 2017 12: +0` etc. What could be the different way doing it?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you store the date as a string.
In this case you could use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date,'%M %d %Y %h: +0') AS converted_date, [...] FROM [...] WHERE converted_date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/92345)

Comment: Thanks! If I may ask, how could I use it in my part on query? Here is my query at the moment: `SELECT * FROM item_histories WHERE name = ? AND date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY`

Comment: Something like this should work:
`SELECT * FROM item_histories WHERE name = ? AND STR_TO_DATE(date,'%M %d %Y %H: +0') >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY`

Comment: What does the error say? I can run the Query after creating a demo tables and replacing `name = ?` by something without a placeholder. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0feaf/1 for example

Comment: Here's my error: `connection.query('SELECT * FROM item_histories WHERE name = ? AND STR_TO_DAT
E(date, '%M %d %Y %H: +0') >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY', ['Falchion Case'] ,
 function(err, rows){

                   ^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for your help Sir!